# ImportError: cannot import name main

Tags: python

I recently rearranged some folders around and a python file I used to run is no longer working. When I try to run the file I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "twitter_stream.py", line 9, in <module>
from tweepy import Stream
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

I don't understand why I no longer have tweepy installed because I just had it When I do a simple 'pip3 install tweepy' I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip3", line 
7, in <module>
from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

I'm not sure what happened here. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to upgrade pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: I get: Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (10.0.1)

Comment: Looks like some changes in new version of pip https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240. Try to install lower version of pip using `pip install pip==9.0.1`

Comment: I downgraded down to 9.0.1, however now after I run pip3 install tweepy I get: Collecting tweepy
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tweepy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tweepy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tweepy

Comment: Install with this command and let's see `pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org tweepy`

Comment: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tweepy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tweepy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tweepy
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Oups, when I see both *Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/ **2.7** /site-packages* and *I run pip **3** install tweepy*, I really think that you have different Python versions installed and maybe a mess between them.

Comment: any suggestions for how to clean that up?